# Mask output of `The following objects are masked from....:` after calling attach() function

Tags: r

I wonder if there is a way to mask the long list output of `The following objects are masked from XXX(position 11):` every time I call `attach()` function?

Comment: Just don't use `attach`. please.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You use `attach` without `detach` - every time you do it new call to attach masks objects attached before (they contain the same names). Either use `detach` or do not use `attach` at all.
Nice discussion and tips are [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/to-attach-or-not-attach-that-is-the-question/).

Comment: Even after detaching, and then attaching, I got the same warning message. Any alternative suggestions this.?

Answer (score 8):

If you look at the down arrow in environment tab. The attached file can appear multiple times. You may need to highlight and run `detach(filename)` several times until all cases are gone then `attach(newfilename)` should have no output message.

[image: attached files under environment tab]

Answer (score 5):

It may be "better" to not use `attach` at all.  On the plus side, you can save some typing if you use `attach`.  Let's say your dataset is called `mydata` and you have variables called `v1`, `v2`, and `v3`.  If you don't attach `mydata`, then you will type `mean(mydata$v1)` to get the mean of `v1`.  If you do attach `mydata`, then you will type `mean(v1)` to get the mean of `v1`.  But, if you don't detach the `mydata` dataset (every time), you'll get the message about the objects being masked going forward.

#### Solution 1 (assuming you want to attach):

1. Use `detach` every time.
2. See Dan Tarr's response if you already have the data attached (and it may be in the global environment several times).  Then, in the future, use detach every time.

#### Solution 2

Don't use `attach`.  Instead, include the dataset name every time you refer to a variable.  The form is `mydata$v1` (name of data set, dollar sign, name of variable).

As for me, I used solution 1 a lot in the past, but I've moved to solution 2.  It's a bit more typing in the beginning, but if you are going to use the code multiple times, it just seems cleaner.

Comment: I  am having same problem. I am not using `attach` but my column contains negative value like `-19.03`. How to work with this situation?

Answer (score 0):

keep using detach(dataframe) multiple times till it returns "object not found" answer and then the masking response will go away

Comment: tried and tested several times over

Answer (score -1):

You actually don't need to use the attach at all. I had the same problem and it was resolved by removing the attach statement.